# .CopyToDataTable() is not available for unit testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I want to write a Testmethod with using `.CopyToDataTable()`. But `.CopyToDataTable()` is not available for unit testing, only `.Copy()`. The Error say's:

> DataRow[] has no extension for .CopyToDataTable().

Why?

In my normal classes the same two lines work and I got no error.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace home.Tests
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class LinkIOTests
    {
        [TestMethod()]
        public void ReadDataTest()
        {
            DataTable ExcelDaten = new DataTable();
            DataTable LineTable = ExcelDaten.Select("STRECKE = 'TestName'").CopyToDataTable();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you use `CopyToDataTable()` outside of your test?

Comment: Basically the error message is telling you that there is no extension method with the name given. You are missing a `using` statement at the top of your file that gives you access to the extension method.

Comment: I think CopyToDataTable() is avialable with using System.Data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [`DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation states:

> Namespace:   System.Data
>
> Assembly:  System.Data.DataSetExtensions (in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll)

This means that in your test project you have to add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` and in your test class add a `using System.Data;`